# Closest textarea w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a value from a  drop-down and on select enter its value in the textarea that follows this selector. I tried defining my var but failed:

```
var input = $(this).closest("input")
```

I don't want to assign IDs since I have the same combination repeat on the page more than once, i.e. selector -> textarea.

Comment: do you actually mean a text area or a text input?  a text area is a completely different tag so you would want to look for `$(this).closest("textarea")`

Comment: You need to provide more context. What is `this` in this instance? Also where does `input` come into play? If you're talking about select boxes and textareas, there should be no need to target an input.

Comment: Closest looks up the dom anyway, I don't believe it would find the next textarea or input.

Answer (score 3):

Since the textarea comes after:

```
 $(this).nextAll('textarea');
```

(or if it's immediately after, always)

```
 $(this).next('textarea');
```

Even better, if the two are in a common wrapper like:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <select />
    <textarea />
</div>
```

then you could say:

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('textarea');
```

Answer (score 2):

Textarea's have their own tag: `<textarea>`. You'll need to do this:

```
var input = $(this).closest('textarea');
```

Also, the `closest` method will find the closest *ancestor* `<textarea>`<sup>1</sup>. If the `<textarea>` you want is a sibling, you can find it with the `siblings` method. If it's a child, then you can use the `find` method or the `children` method.

---

<sup>1: Assuming `this` is not a `<textarea>` itself, in which case `closest` would find `this`. This is one of the ways `closest` differs from the `parents` method.</sup>